# TableView cell is being shown again

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I'm having a problem where if my table view scrolls down enough, it will repeat the first element that was on the table view. I honestly don't know why it's doing that, my only guess is that I need to somehow read if that cell previously exists but in the tutorials I've seen, they don't really have that problem. When implementing the cellForRowAtIndex path method it just works and doesn't repeat cells.

```
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cellIdentifier = "chatbubbleCell"
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! ChatBubbleCell

    /* Configure the cell */
    var yAxis: CGFloat = 5.0
    // Setup the chat bubble view
    if outgoingSender {
        let outgoingChatBubbleData = ChatBubbleData(text: messagesArray[indexPath.row], image: nil, profileImage: UIImage(named: "chatIcon"), date: NSDate(), type: .Mine)
        let outgoingChatBubble = ChatBubble(data: outgoingChatBubbleData, startY: yAxis)
        cell.contentView.addSubview(outgoingChatBubble)
    } else {
        let incomingChatBubbleData = ChatBubbleData(text: messagesArray[indexPath.row], image: nil, profileImage: UIImage(named: "chatIcon"), date: NSDate(), type: .Opponent)
        var incomingChatBubble = ChatBubble(data: incomingChatBubbleData, startY: yAxis)
        cell.contentView.addSubview(incomingChatBubble)
    }

    return cell
}
```

As you can see all I am doing is checking if the message incoming is outgoing or incoming, and then just initializing a custom view which contains a label, and then I just add it to the content view of the cell.

Any help would be appreciated, thank you.

--
Was told by Paul below that cells are being reused and that's why it's showing the same one. So I put my cell logic into my prototype cell class as shown

```
   let outgoingChatBubbleData = ChatBubbleData(text: "", image: nil, profileImage: UIImage(named: "chatIcon"), date: NSDate(), type: .Mine)
    let incomingChatBubbleData = ChatBubbleData(text: "", image: nil, profileImage: UIImage(named: "chatIcon"), date: NSDate(), type: .Opponent)
```

and then set its properties in cellForRowAtIndexPath

```
if outgoingSender {
    cell.outgoingChatBubbleData.text = messagesArray[indexPath.row]
    var incomingChatBubble = ChatBubble(data: cell.outgoingChatBubbleData, startY: yAxis)
    // Attach to bubble view?
} else {
    cell.incomingChatBubbleData.text = messagesArray[indexPath.row]
    let outgoingChatBubble = ChatBubble(data: cell.incomingChatBubbleData, startY: yAxis)
     // Attach to bubble view?
}
```

But now my problem is that I'm not sure how to attach "ChatBubble" which is of type UIView to the cell without using addSubview() in the cellForRowAtIndexPath method

Comment: Cell objects are reused. Adding subviews in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` is a bad idea, since when the cell object is reused, the previously added subviews are still there. You need to ensure you remove the subview previously added, or better, add the chat bubble view in your cell prototype and set its data in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` So that you don't need to add subviews each time.

Comment: @Paulw11 Ok I believe I get what you are saying. I went ahead and put my logic into my prototype cell class - If you could look at that and suggest a way of how I could attach the view without using addSubView that would be great. Thank you for your help!

Comment: I believe what paul is suggesting is you add an instance of `ChatBubble` as a property of your `UITableViewCell` subclass and add it as a subview early in your table view cell's lifecycle, perhaps in `awakeFromNib` or add it in your storyboard. Then simply update the data `ChatBubble` displays in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`.

Answer (score 0):

One tricky way is to add subviews on cell initing, and just set `isHidden` property for subviews in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`. You might get what you want.